# Broadcom wireless card disappears after restart

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

I used 'additional drivers' to install 'Broadcom STA wireless driver' and it returns an error. Within `jockey.log` it says the following numerous times.

```
2011-02-14 21:24:06,945 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

After it returns the error the network card will work temporarily until I restart the laptop. When I restart I got to go through the procedure again of trying to activate the driver, returns an error however it works temporarily.

The network card is as follows on a Dell Inspiron 1545:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] Rev 01
```

I have been trying to solve this myself for many hours. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Inspiron 1545 with the 14e4:4315 card, and for me the broadcom-sta driver works without issue. (I've worked really hard to get the non-sta/wl drivers working on all kinds of distros and this particular wlan card just seems to be difficult)

I am guessing that there's some kind of error with the blacklisting of the other available broadcom drivers that ship w/ the kernel (b43, b43xx b43legacy). if you post the output of your  error message when you install, lsmod when it's working and `lsmod` when it's not... that should be a good start.

you should also look at the contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`. it should contain the following, which disables the wrong drivers from being loaded:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Setup to always load at boot time](https://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt)

Answer (score 0):

one way to diagnose this would be to run, on a terminal:

```
dpkg --list firmware-b43-*
```

look at the package names and statuses (the two leftmost columns read "ii" for installed packages).

I see three b43-related packages in the list of possibilities:

- firmware-b43-installer
- firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
- firmware-b43legacy-installer

For your card (LP-PHY variant) you'd want firmware-b43-lpphy-installer to be installed. I have seen the driver installation tool get it "wrong" and install firmware-b43-installer instead (but that installs a module that doesn't work with the LP-PHY hardware).

If it turns out you don't have firmware-b43-lpphy-installer installed, do so by running this on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Make sure to have a fallback wired connection handy, if the firmware-b43-lpphy-installer fails, you can remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```